# Check my proof that $Tr(f \otimes g) = Tr(f)Tr(g)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, tensor-products

Chapter 2, section 6, Exercise 4, Quantum Groups by Christian Kassel

Let $f \in End(V)$ and $g \in End(W)$ where $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional vector spaces over a filed $K$. I'm attempting to show that $Tr(f \otimes g) = Tr(f)Tr(g)$.

---

My attempt:

Let $\{v_i\}_{i \in I}$ and $\{w_r\}_{r \in R}$ be bases for $V$ and $W$ respectively.

Then $f(v_i) = \sum_{j \in I} f^j_i v_j$ for some $f_i^j \in K$

and $g(w_r) = \sum_{s \in R} g^s_r w_s$ for some $g_r^s \in K$

So $Tr(f)Tr(g) = (\sum_{i \in I} f_i^i)(\sum_{r \in J} g_r^r)=\sum_{i \in I, r \in R}f_i^ig_r^r$

Now, $\{v_i \otimes w_r\}_{i \in I, r \in R}$ is a basis for $V \otimes W$ and we have that:

$(f \otimes g)(v_i \otimes w_r)=f(v_i) \otimes g(w_r) = \sum_{j \in I} f_i^jv_j \otimes \sum_{s \in R}g_r^sw_s = \sum_{j \in I, s \in R}f_i^jg_r^s(v_j \otimes w_s)$

And so $Tr(f \otimes g) = \sum_{i \in I, r \in R} f_i^ig_r^r$

Is this all correct?

Comment: Yes. Though the immediate way to see this is that the matrix of the tensor product is the matrix of $f$ with every entry replaced by whatever coefficient is there times the matrix of $g.$ The result is then obvious.

Comment: if you draw out the details on showing me why this is what the matrix of the tensor product is i'll give you a nice green checkmark